# Batch to search different file formats in directory recursively

Tags: batch-file

I tested the below script and knew that this will search for .c and .h results and redirect them to out.txt.

Is there anyway to write single findstr line to search both .c and .h files?

Since the 2 findstr lines writes to same out.txt, first line of the 2nd file search writes right next to the last line of the 1st findstr output. How to write 2nd findstr output always in a newline? Means insert a newline and execute the 2nd findstr syntax? Is it feasible

Script used:

`````
echo.
echo.
del find.txt
set x="\n"
for /F %%i in (output.txt) do (
echo.
findstr /S /N /C:%%i "D:\GTest_Automation_Scripts\*.c">>find.txt
echo.
findstr /S /N /C:%%i "D:\GTest_Automation_Scripts\*.h">>find.txt
pause
)````
However, Can someone help to achieve the same with single FINDSTR command. Tried to search files using comma separation, semi colon separation, & and && separations, but didn't work.
`````

Comment: open cdm.exe, type for /? and read the help output regarding the different switches. pay particular attention to the /R switch.

Comment: I would suggest that you forget about a [tag:for-loop] completely. You may get all of the information you need from the output after entering `findstr /?` in a Command Prompt window. _(Pay particular attention to the **`/G`** option)_. However, if your files have none standard line endings, you may need to consider a different tool, _(or creating modified versions of your files first)_. Perhaps in that case, you should consider [tag:powershell] or [tag:jscript].

Comment: Is there anyway to write single findstr line to search both .c and .h files?

Since the 2 findstr lines writes to same out.txt, first line of the 2nd file search writes right next to the last line of the 1st findstr output. How to write 2nd findstr output always in a newline? Means insert a newline and execute the 2nd findstr syntax? Is it feasible